# How do I open the new AVD manager on Linux from the command line?

Tags: android, linux

Before march 2017 I used `android avd` command to open AVD manager on Linux from the command line. It does not work anymore:

```
$ Android/Sdk/tools/android avd
The android command is no longer available.
For manual SDK and AVD management, please use Android Studio.
For command-line tools, use tools/bin/sdkmanager and tools/bin/avdmanager
```

How do I open the new AVD manager on Linux from the command line?

Comment: Looks like impossible now. Why do you need it?

Comment: to configure a virtual device on my laptop. I can't start it with Android Studio either.

Comment: Then use `tools/bin/avdmanager` from `ANDROID_HOME`

Comment: thank you, but this doesn't open the AVD manager neither

Comment: It should not it is command line tool to create avd images

Comment: so `tools/bin/avdmanager` do not open AVD manager, and my question is how to open AVD manager. I can't launch anymore the AVD manager wizard. so like you said "Looks like impossible now"

Comment: Looks like we are in the loop. You said you want to configure virtual device on your laptop. With `tools/bin/avdmanager` you can create a new image or overwrite the existing image